# Warning: data for page "/blog/....") is 569 kB which exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance

Tags: next.js, vercel, mdxjs

What is the best way to handle "Warning: data for page "/blog/....") is 569 kB which exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance" in nextjs for mdx file without using largePageDataBytes in next.config.js. I'm using mdx-bundler for mdx files.

Answer (score 10):

The warning is there for a reason and i would recommend to find a solution to decrease page data.

For the record, threshold "can" be increased via next.config.js

```js
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  experimental: {
  //largePageDataBytes: 128 * 1000, // 128KB by default
    largePageDataBytes: 128 * 100000,
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.getting this error